# Sql select statement that can count rows in a table not in the main query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an old query that I want to now count the rows of wbs.WBSNodeGuid in a table not included in the main query. I've tried doing this with COUNT() in a separate select statement within the main SELECT, but of course it doesn't understand wbs within the SELECT Count() statement. How can I count the rows from the other table to match the main query's current row's wbs.WBSNodeGuid value?

Note that this example is much simpler than the original, but should get acress the general idea of what I tried and what I'm looking for.

```
    SELECT wbs.WBSNodeGuid
    , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Marker mkr WHERE mkr.WBSNodeGuid = wbs.WBSNodeGuid AND Deleted = 0)
    FROM WBSNode wbs


Above is a simplified version. Below is the actual that I am trying to add to.

SELECT wbs.WBSNodeText
           , wbs.WBSNodeOverallIndex
           , wbs.WBSNodePath
           --***THIS IS THE COLUMN I'M TRYING TO ADD**** (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Marker mkr WHERE mkr.WBSNodeGuid = wbs.WBSNodeGuid AND Deleted = 0)
           , insp.WBSNodeInspectionGuid
           , insp.WBSInspInspector
           , insp.WBSInspDate
           , insp.WBSInspNote
           , image0.WBSInspImageBlobPartialPath Image0
           , image1.WBSInspImageBlobPartialPath Image1
           , opt.POptionDefaultValue NetworkImagePath
           , opt2.POptionDefaultValue WBSPathStartDepth
FROM ProjectOption opt
            , ProjectOption opt2
            , WBSNode wbs
            , WBSNodeInspection insp

LEFT OUTER JOIN WBSNodeInspectionImage image0
ON   insp.WBSNodeInspectionGuid = image0.WBSNodeInspectionGuid
AND image0.WBSInspImageIndex = 0
AND image0.Deleted = 0

LEFT OUTER JOIN WBSNodeInspectionImage image1
ON   insp.WBSNodeInspectionGuid = image1.WBSNodeInspectionGuid
AND image1.WBSInspImageIndex = 1
AND image1.Deleted = 0

INNER JOIN Marker mkr ON mkr.WBSNodeGuid = wbs.WBSNodeGuid AND mkr.Deleted = 0


WHERE wbs.WBSNodeGuid = insp.WBSNodeGuid
     AND opt.ProjectOption = 'NetworkPathToProjectImages'
     AND opt2.ProjectOption = 'LevelToStartLocationPortionOfWBSNodePath'

              AND opt.Deleted = 0
              AND opt2.Deleted = 0
              AND wbs.Deleted = 0
              AND insp.Deleted = 0

ORDER BY wbs.WBSNodeText, insp.WBSInspDate
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  Your query looks fine to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work?

```
SELECT count(distinct wbs.WBSNodeGuid) as [Count]
FROM WBSNode wbs
  INNER JOIN Marker mkr ON mkr.WNSNodeGuid = wbs.WBSNodeGuid AND Deleted = 0
```

If that's not what you're looking for, how about this?

```
SELECT wbs.WBSNodeGuid
  ,count(*) as [Count]
FROM WBSNode wbs
  INNER JOIN Marker mkr ON mkr.WNSNodeGuid = wbs.WBSNodeGuid AND Deleted = 0
GROUP BY wbs.WBSNodeGuid
```

Based on your new updates, here this query should work

```
SELECT wbs.WBSNodeText
           , wbs.WBSNodeOverallIndex
           , wbs.WBSNodePath
           ,(select count (*) from Marker mkr WHERE mkr.WBSNodeGuid = wbs.WBSNodeGuid AND mkr.Deleted = 0 ) as [Deleted Count]
           , insp.WBSNodeInspectionGuid
           , insp.WBSInspInspector
           , insp.WBSInspDate
           , insp.WBSInspNote
           , image0.WBSInspImageBlobPartialPath Image0
           , image1.WBSInspImageBlobPartialPath Image1
           , opt.POptionDefaultValue NetworkImagePath
           , opt2.POptionDefaultValue WBSPathStartDepth
FROM ProjectOption opt
            , ProjectOption opt2
            , WBSNode wbs
            , WBSNodeInspection insp

LEFT OUTER JOIN WBSNodeInspectionImage image0
ON   insp.WBSNodeInspectionGuid = image0.WBSNodeInspectionGuid
AND image0.WBSInspImageIndex = 0
AND image0.Deleted = 0

LEFT OUTER JOIN WBSNodeInspectionImage image1
ON   insp.WBSNodeInspectionGuid = image1.WBSNodeInspectionGuid
AND image1.WBSInspImageIndex = 1
AND image1.Deleted = 0

WHERE wbs.WBSNodeGuid = insp.WBSNodeGuid
     AND opt.ProjectOption = 'NetworkPathToProjectImages'
     AND opt2.ProjectOption = 'LevelToStartLocationPortionOfWBSNodePath'

              AND opt.Deleted = 0
              AND opt2.Deleted = 0
              AND wbs.Deleted = 0
              AND insp.Deleted = 0

ORDER BY wbs.WBSNodeText, insp.WBSInspDate
```

Comment: The original is very complex, joining the marker table in the main query so far has been a problem. And also, it would not work because there are a number of other joins, so doing a distinct as you show is not possible, I do not believe.

Comment: See my 2nd suggestion. Without seeing the table schemas and data it's hard to know what you're looking for.

Comment: I do not think a join on the main query will work, that is why I'm trying to handle it as a separate SQL. For example, simply trying your join in the original gives me a "wbs.WBSNodeGuid" Could not be bound error

Comment: Why wouldn't a join on the main query work? Also it looks like perhaps there is a typo in your column names, it's called WNSNodeGuid in one table and WBSNodeGuid in the other table. Is this correct? You need to post the schema of the 2 tables and I can give you a working query

Comment: Yes, I fixed the typo. I'm adding the original query.

Comment: "wbs.WBSNodeGuid" Could not be bound error, this indicates that table does not contain a column WBSNodeGuid. Can you please post the table schema in your original question?

Comment: WBSNodeGuid is the primary key of the WBSNode (wbs) table. It exists.

Comment: Please see my latest edit on my answer. It should give you the [Count] column you need. If it doesn't work, please post the complete SQL Error message here

Comment: Also, I would advise NOT using the FROM X, Y, Z syntax. I would use FROM X inner join Y on Y.Id = x.Id inner join Z on Z.id = x.Id etc.

Comment: -I normally use joins, but this was created by someone else. Also, interestingly, your example worked, but I don't see the difference from the examples in my question that did not work. What am I missing?

Comment: I removed the INNER JOIN Marker, which is messing up your query.

Comment: Ah. Though I didn't have that originally. Must have been getting my wires crossed during my testing. Thanks for helping me sort it out.